# ssh command related problem

Tags: ssh, connection, reset

I am facing problem with the `ssh` command currently. Earlier, it was working just fine, but now when I am trying to execute the same command, it says, `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer.` How do I access the web account now?

---

`ssh -v` output:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to iiit.ac.in [10.4.3.20]
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_file: read from key file /home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa failed: Is a directory
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/usr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Could you put the result of `ssh -v` when connecting to this server ?

Comment: In the directory `~/.ssh`, there should be only files,one of them being `id_rsa` which should be an RSA private key.  But it looks like you have a directory named id_rsa instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for this problem. I just share my same experience. check your server's routing. Maybe there is a bad route or some default gateway have been cause this problem.

I have the same problem on my CenOS server and try to connect it from Ubuntu. I found the server has 2 default gateway, when i remove the second one, the problem solved.